# Non-equivalent metrics on $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading a paper on continued fractions and it uses the following result on Lie Groups:

> Fix **an** arbitrary left-invariant metric $d$ on $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ ...

This phrase really throws me off... How many such left-invariant metrics are there? Consider two maps,

$$ z \mapsto \frac{a_0z+b_0}{c_0z+d_0} , \hspace{0.25in}z \mapsto \frac{a_1z+b_1}{c_1z+d_1} $$

each with $ad-bc=1$, what is the appropriate notion of distance here?

Can someone illustrate **two non-equivalent left-invariant metrics** on the space of Fractional Linear Transformations?

If it is easier, I will [mysteriously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)#Topology_and_universal_cover) ask for different (non-equivalent) metrics on $T^1(\mathbb{H}) \simeq PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$

These are not **points** in the Hyperbolic plane, these are **geodesics** in the hyperbolic plane.  In the picture below you can see semi-circles in the checkered pattern below, these can be identified with unit tangent vectors

---

related

- [Expression of the Hyperbolic Distance in the Upper Half Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160338/expression-of-the-hyperbolic-distance-in-the-upper-half-plane)
- [Description of SU(1, 1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59717/description-of-su1-1)
- [What are elements in $SU(1, 1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229392/what-are-elements-in-su1-1)

[image]

---

There's some question of what I mean by "equivalent" "metric" (along the lines of Bill Clinton's what does "is" mean?)  I am just trying to see if there are really any "different"  left-invariant metrics.

- [Example of equivalent but not strongly equivalent metrics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072984/example-of-equivalent-but-not-strongly-equivalent-metrics)
- [Understanding equivalent metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150737/understanding-equivalent-metric-spaces)

Left invariant is pretty restrictive.  I believe in the case of $\mathbb{H}$ hyperbolic plane there is only one translation invariant constant curvature metric up to scalar multiplication (so we can set curvature to -1).

My bst guess for $T^1(\mathbb{H})$ is $\frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2} + d\theta^2 $ where $\theta$ is the angle of the unit tangent vector.

---

Is the left-invariant metric on $T^1(\mathbb{H})=PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ unique up to scalar multiplication ?

Comment: Two questions: what do you mean by "metric," and what do you mean by "equivalent" here?

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply any left-invariant metric by a positive number and you will get a different left-invariant metric.