# Determine the matricies in SU(1,1) by explicitly writing entries of each matrix

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I am trying to show that any element in $SU(1,1)$ can be expressed as,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a &  b\\
\overline b & \overline a 
\end{bmatrix}$$
from the definition. That is, if $A \in U(1,1)$ with $det(A)=1$ then $A \in SU(1,1)$.

I derived a matrix equation for matrices in $U(m,n)$,
$$U(m,n)=\{A \in GL(m+n, \mathbb{R})\:;\: \overline A^\intercal I_{m,n}A=I_{m,n}\}$$

I tried to solve this equation, but I cannot do it.

This has already been partly answered here: [Description of SU(1, 1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59717/description-of-su1-1) but it seems incomplete (no justification).

They wrote:
You precisely get that the general form of such matrix is

$$
  U = \left( \begin{array}{cc} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{array} \right)
$$
where $ \vert \alpha \vert^2 - \vert \beta \vert^2 = 1$, $ \vert \delta \vert^2 - \vert \gamma \vert^2 = 1$ and $(\alpha \, \beta^\ast)^\ast = \gamma \, \delta^\ast$. This implies $\delta = \alpha^\ast$ and $\gamma = \beta^\ast$ as you surely know.

How is that last step justified?

Comment: Found a good resource. This question is answered in depth here: http://arkadiusz-jadczyk.eu/blog/2017/03/su11-parametrization/